# Why isn't VueJS displaying my nested routes in the html?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm learning VueJS Routing by reading the docs. I opened an example from the page and added my own nested routes as "/user/foo/posts/1, /user/foo/posts/2, /user/foo/posts/3" and expected them to display properly

I've tried reading the starting example carefully, as well as the documentation for routing (the page on [Nested Routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html)). Nothing is cluing me in on whats wrong.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>
    <router-link to="/user/foo">/user/foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/user/foo/profile">/user/foo/profile</router-link>
    <router-link to="/user/foo/posts">/user/foo/posts</router-link>
    <!-- stuff I added myself below this line (comment is not present in original code) -->
    <router-link to="/user/foo/posts/1">/user/foo/posts/1</router-link>
    <router-link to="/user/foo/posts/2">/user/foo/posts/2</router-link>
    <router-link to="/user/foo/posts/3">/user/foo/posts/3</router-link>
  </p>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const User = {
  template: `
    <div class="user">
      <h2>User {{ $route.params.id }}</h2>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  `
}

const UserHome = { template: '<div>Home</div>' }
const UserProfile = { template: '<div>Profile</div>' }
const UserPosts = { template: '<div>Posts</div>' }

const PostOne = { template: '<p>Gonna clone Twitter</p>'}
const PostTwo = { template: '<h5>Not gonna clone IG until Im done Twitter</h5'}
const PostThree = { template: '<p>Gonna be a paid web developer</p>'}

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/user/:id', component: User,
      children: [
        // UserHome will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
        // when /user/:id is matched
        { path: '', component: UserHome },

        // UserProfile will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
        // when /user/:id/profile is matched
        { path: 'profile', component: UserProfile },

        // UserPosts will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
        // when /user/:id/posts is matched
        { path: 'posts', component: UserPosts,
            children: [
            // the posts within /posts
            { path: "1", component: PostOne },
            { path: "2", component: PostTwo },
            { path: "3", component: PostThree }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})

const app = new Vue({ router }).$mount('#app')
```

Specifically, I'm expecting /1 to say "Gonna clone Twitter", /2 to say "Not gonna clone IG until Im done Twitter" (in h5 tags), and /3 to say "Gonna be a paid web developer".

I expected to see those texts loading under "User foo
Posts" when the links are clicked on, and I didn't.

edit: Note that I've only tried running this inside of a JSFiddle environment. here is the fiddle itself where I want the code to run properly: https://jsfiddle.net/rolandmackintosh/use04pwf/9/

Answer (score 1):

So the problem you are facing is that you are not only nesting routes, you are nesting components.  When a route has it's own component plus children routes, there needs to be a `<router-view>` for the child(ren) to load into.  This change to `UserPosts` will make it work for you:

```
const UserPosts = { template: '<div>Posts<router-view></router-view></div>' }
```